# Mostrar datos con base a un select option de otra tabla

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Tengo un detalle ahora de acuerdo al *option* que selecciono, me vuelve a mostrar toda mi plantilla en mi *DataTable*, estoy usando plantilla para el *DataTable* por si se llegan a preguntar. Busco la forma de que no me vuelva a aparecer duplicado pero no averiguo la forma de como evitar eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código de correo_oficinas.php:

```
<?php include_once 'vistas/parte_superior.php';?>
<!--Inicio del contenido -->
<div class="container">
<h2>Correo A Oficinas</h2>
<?php
  include_once 'bd/conexion.php';
  $objeto = new Conexion();
  $conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
  $consultaO =  "SELECT * FROM actsa";   
  //consulta de actsa
  $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consultaO);
  $resultado->execute();
  $dataO=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="oficina" class="col-form-label">Oficina</label>
              <select id="select"> 
               <option>Mostrar Oficinas</option>
                    <?php  
                      foreach ($dataO as $valores){                            
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores["id_oficina"].'">'.$valores["oficina"].'</option>';                            
                          $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];//aqui estamos recibiendo la variable opcion
                        }
                    ?>
              </select>
              <table id="colaboradores" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:100%">
                <thead class="text-center">
                  <tr>                            
                    <th>OFICINA</th>                               
                    <th>NOMBRE EMPLEADO</th>                                
                    <th>CORREO</th> 
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>                            
                </thead>
                <tbody class ="text-center">
                <?php 
                        $tmp = "";//aqui vamos a guardar la cadena que vamos a mostrar  
                        include_once 'bd/conexion.php';
                        switch ($opcion) {                            
                            case 1:
                                $id = $_POST['id'];//aqui recibimos el id
                                $query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM empleados where id_oficina = $id");
                                while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $tmp .= "<tr>                               
                                              <td>". $data['id_oficina'] ."</td>                                                                
                                              <td>". $data['nom_empleado'] ."</td> 
                                              <td>". $data['correo'] ."</td> 
                                            </tr>";
                                } //esto lo puse separado para que lo tuvieras más visual, pero realmente debe ir en una sola linea
                                echo $tmp;//enviamos la cadena con los datos
                                break;  
                              }              
                ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>    

<?php include_once 'vistas/parte_inferior.php';?>
```

el código de main.js :
me imagino que ha de ser por este mismo que me vuelve a mostrar mi plantilla

```
//codigo para ejecutar correo_oficinas.php 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#select").on('change', function() {
var id = $(this).val();
var opcion = 1;
$.post("Correo_Oficinas.php", { opcion: opcion, id: id }, function(r) {
        $("#colaboradores").html(r);
    });
  });
});
```

Espero puedan orientarme un poco más y gracias... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a SOes.

Lo que puedes hacer es que con JavaScript crees una función para que cada que cambies la opción en tu select, se actualice lo demás, mira te muestro como se hace con jQuery:

```
$("#select").on('change', function () {
var id = $(this).val();
var opcion = 1;
$.post("ruta_del_archivo.php", { opcion: opcion, id: id},
function (res) {
$("#colaboradores").html(res);
});
});
```

ahora, con esto nos vamos al archivo php:
(yo suelo hacer esto con switch case porque uso el mismo archivo para manejar varios selects)

```
<?php

$opcion = $_POST['opcion'];//aqui estamos recibiendo la variable opcion
$tmp = "";//aqui vamos a guardar la cadena que vamos a mostrar

require "../conexion/Conexion.php";

switch ($opcion) {

    case 1:
        $id = $_POST['id'];//aqui recibimos el id
        $query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM empleados where id_oficina = $id");
        while ($data = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tmp .= "<tr>                               
                      <td>". $data['oficina'] ."</td>                                                                
                      <td>". $data['nom_empleado'] ."</td> 
                      <td>". $data['correo'] ."</td> 
                    </tr>";
        } //esto lo puse separado para que lo tuvieras más visual, pero realmente debe ir en una sola linea
        echo $tmp;//enviamos la cadena con los datos
        break;
```

y listo!

basicamente lo que estamos haciendo es ejecutar esa consulta cada que se cambie el valor de select, y una vez que se ejecuta, actualizamos la tabla.
Espero que te sirva! cualquier duda puedes preguntarme en los comentarios.

Comment: marca error en la variable $opcion que no esta declarada y ya lo hice.

Comment: pusiste el código dentro del $(document).ready ?

Comment: si, pero en el archivo php es donde me bota el erro de la variable no definida

Comment: te propondría que sigamos con esto en un chat para poder ayudarte más a fondo con tu problema, pero debes tener 20 de reputación para participar en las salas de chat :/

Comment: A ver. en que parte te salta el error de que la variable no está definida?

Comment: $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];//en la variable $opcion me marca el error al igual que en el fetch_assoc